# React Helmet is really slow. Do I need 'hreflang' links client-side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hreflang, react-helmet

I've got a page on my website which has a lot of `alternate` links caused by 5 different languages and content for 31 countries. In sum 155 different links.

But React Helmet is reaaaally slow and the page freezes for some seconds. That's really annoying.

So is it possible to speed it up and make no difference between client and server rendering? Or is it a good idea to render the tags only serverside?

Comment: definitely recommend only rendering the tags on the server, as far as performance & SEO are concerned.

Comment: That's what I am doing now. Are there any disadvantages for clients?